# Bessel Recurrence relations

Tags: recurrence-relations, bessel-functions

Really short question: I am following the steps laid out by Arfken and Brown in *Mathematical Methods for Physicists* to derive the first two recurrence formulae for Bessel Functions. Using the generating function 
$$
g(x,t) = \exp\left[\frac{x}{2}(t-t^{-1})\right] = \sum_n J_n(x) t^n
$$
I understand that I have to get the t and x derivatives and then compare the powers of t. But when I do the x derivative, I end up with the recurring relation:
$$
t \sum J_n t^n - t^{-1} \sum J_n t^n = 2 \sum J'_n t^n\\
\implies J_{n+1} - J_{n-1} = 2\, J'_n
$$
The book (and elsewhere on the internet) the left side is flipped, i.e.: 
$$
J_{n-1} - J_{n+1} = 2\, J'_n.
$$
So, what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have derived
$$
\sum J_n t^{n+1} - \sum J_n t^{n-1} = 2 \sum J'_n t^n
$$
(with appropriate indices and special cases on the boundary). If we just glance at that equation, we might think it's telling us that $J_{n+1}-J_{n-1}=2J'_n$. However, when we have two equal power series, what we should do is look at *the coefficients of $t^n$ on both sides* and set them equal to each other.

The coefficient of $t^n$ in $\sum J_n t^{n+1}$ is equal to $J_{n-1}$. (Do you agree?) The coefficient of $t^n$ in $\sum J_n t^{n-1}$ is equal to $J_{n+1}$. Therefore the coefficients of $t^n$ on the two sides are equal:
$$
J_{n-1} - J_{n+1} = 2J'_n.
$$